# A word for a place where you store antiques

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

I'm writing a song and I'm trying to come up with a word for a place, a room, a shop, or even a piece of furniture where people store old things or collectible objects. The idea is to imply that something is old or is more like a collection piece now by saying it is getting saved there (in the song).

Comment: A ***museum***...

Comment: An attic.......?

Comment: A safe? A shoebox? An antique store?

Comment: display cabinet?

Comment: What words have you already considered and rejected, and why? You need to provide more criteria for what is acceptable and what isn't.

Comment: armoire or (wall) niche.....ambry, rare.

Comment: How about an “antiquarian depository,” where “antiquarian” means “of or relating to antiquarians or antiques” and “depository” means “a place where things are stored”?

Comment: @Jim A “museum” is simply “an institution devoted to the procurement, care, study, and display of objects of lasting interest or value.” It doesn’t necessarily house old things.

Comment: @NathanM -  Hmmm. All the museums i’ve been in had only old things.  Well except for the “MoMA” types. Anyway it was a comment not an answer.

Comment: I realize that. I was simply making a point.

Comment: @Jim, I was just saying that museums aren’t inherently places that store old things.

Comment: A reliquary is one such place, but it might be a bit ornate for your purposes.

Answer (score 5):

A hutch or a curio cabinet would be used to store curiosities within someone's house or apartment. If you're speaking of china specifically, a china cabinet would work.

A shop/place where used or old collectible items are sold could be an antique store, vintage shop, thrift store, flea market, swap meet (regional), estate sale (implies that a collector is going to the deceased's house rather than a store), or even a garage sale depending on what you're going for.

Comment: Brilliant ideas!!

Answer (score 1):

It’s called a **[lumber room](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lumber_room)**.  The term is common in English literature, since the writers of a certain period (think Jane Austen) tended to set their stories in the large houses that contained them.

There is a short story by Saki, called *The Lumber Room*, which can be read online in several places, including [East of the Web](http://eastoftheweb.com/short-stories/UBooks/LumRoo.shtml), from which I copied the following passage, which describes what young Nicholas sees as he escapes from his severe aunt and finds his way into the forbidden space:

> ...objects of delight and interest claiming his instant attention; there were quaint twisted candlesticks in the shape of snakes, and a teapot fashioned like a china duck, out of whose open beak the tea was supposed to come. How dull and shapeless the nursery teapot seemed in comparison! And there was a carved sandalwood box packed tight with aromatic cotton-wool, and between the layers of cotton-wool were little brass figures, hump-necked bulls, and peacocks and goblins, delightful to see and to handle.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the use of one of the definitions of "gallery", "archive", or "repository" would be suitable, or use of the mere description of something as a "curio" (often used with cabinet) implying such an object's place as part of a "collection".

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/gallery

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/archive

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/repository

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/curio